# Octave - any examples of solving non-linear equations system with sqp function?

Tags: octave

I need example of solving non-linear euations system with octave "sqp" function, but not found anything like it (yes, maybe my knowledge of math is too bad for documentation :-) )

I have system of next 2 equations :

```
tan(x*y+0.3)-x^2 = 0
x^2+2*y^2-1 = 0
```

How can I use "sqp" for it?

Comment: **sqp** stands for successive quadratic programming and it is intended to solve optimization problems, expressed as objective function. Since you don't have a function to optimize, **sqp** is not what you need. Try **fsolve** instead. More information at: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Solvers.html

Answer (score 0):

Found example on http://realsuddenlike.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/nonlinear-minimization-in-octave-sequential-quadratic-programming/

For
        f(x,y)=x^2+y^2.
Work's next code

```
    function out=obj_fcn1(x)
    x=x(:);
    out=x’*x;
    end

    [x_f,j_f]=sqp(x_0,@(x)obj_fcn1(x),[],@(x)bndfcn(x));
```

My system can be adapted
    f(x_1, ..., x_n) = f_1(x1, ..., x_n)^2 + ... + f_n(x1, ..., x_n)^2 = 0